# How to read .class file from my Java programm?

Tags: java, bytecode

Anybody knows how to load .class content to humman-readable format in memory? I'm should write program which will manipulate with info from this file

Comment: What are you looking for? Methods name sand arguments? Or the byte code of the methods?

Comment: I'm want to develop application which will find all dependency of input class filename in classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply looking for the declaration of methods names and arguments, fields, extended types, etc. then you should use Java reflection and introspection features.

If you want to access the byte code of compiled methods, then have a look at the [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) or Apache bcel libraries.

Comment: i asume you mean reflection, since i never heard of reflexion

Comment: @PhilippSander Indeed. Reflexion is the French word. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can dissasemble the .class file by using the [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) tool.

```
javap MyClass
```

Suppose we have a simple class :

```
public class Test {
    public void test() {...}
}
```

Invoking `javap Test` from the command-line will print:

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
  public void test();
}
```

Then you can store this info in a data structure and if you want to dynamically construct object/invoke methods, you can use [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).